# Is it possible to historical junit data from bamboo?

Tags: junit, bamboo, reportportal

I'd like to look at the option to export junit test results from bamboo, to put into a tool such as reportportal (or something else).

Anyone managed this with REST?
Or any tools that I've overlooked so far?